# Footer isn't sticking to bottom of page on index only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I have an issue where my footer only is stuck to the bottom of the page on the index, applying any sort of "sticky footer" CSS fixes the footer for every other page, but breaks the footer for index. As in, it floats up.

Here is the general CSS I've tried:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Which again, works fine on most other pages, however not on the index.

You can see my live index here: http://goo.gl/XUUCjW

And an example of a non sticky footer on one of my pages here: http://goo.gl/uhd1h4

Comment: set position absolute to relative..

Comment: Footer on index page also isn't sticky.

Comment: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/ try this

Comment: @ChiragSenjaliya Setting relative doesn't seem to stick the footer. I added a !important too just in case, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @jQuery00 Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around this is to do the following:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The reason for the margin-bottom on the body is that when you push the footer to the bottom it will overlap the content of anything above it. I found that 60px worked well for me but you may have a deeper or smaller footer so adjust accordingly.